# How do I write a macro/web scraper for facebook chat?

Tags: java, python, facebook, perl, facebook-chat

My old non-smart phone doesn't support GROUP facebook chat, so I was trying to find a way to scrape facebook GROUP messages and send them as text messages to the phone. I know some amount of Perl webscraping (HTML::TableExtract,WWW::Mechanize, LWP, the like) but I wasn't able to infiltrate facebook even when I provided my script my username and password.

Is there any way to get such a web scraper to work? Any APIs or toolkits I should look at? I'm not quite sure how to get started on this project. At worst, I could try to write a macro that copies text from certain locations on my browser....

edit: A cookie jar sounds like a good idea, I'll look into it. Here's a snippet of (bad) code.

```
        open(PERSONAL, "personal.txt");
        my @pers = <PERSONAL>;

        $ua -> get($cur_url);
        $ua -> form_id("login_form");
        chomp($pers[0]);
        $ua -> field("email", $pers[0]);
        chomp($pers[1]);
        $ua -> field("pass", $pers[1]);
        $ua -> click_button(value =>"Log In");

        $ua -> get("https://m.facebook.com/groups/170930939594231/");

        $ua -> save_content($dir."/group.html");
```

Comment: Perl www::mechanize should do the job if you know how to use it. Add a cookie jar and agent alias and you should be good to go. If you post some code as to what exactly you have tried we may be able to help.

Comment: Facebooks chat is just xmpp/jabber. WWW::Mechanize is the wrong tool for the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the xmpp [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) facebook provides. No need to scrape things.